# PDFBOX use in android

Tags: android, pdfbox

I am unable to run pdf text extract using pdfbox in android emulator. The code however works well when run as standalone java application.

PDFBOXv1.8.4 is used and Build path is setup appropriately with the pdfbox jar .What could have possibly gone wrong?

Also I have seen some posts advising not to use pdfbox as the drawables(java.awt.*) are not supported by android library. Is this really the case? Can i still hope to get my simple pdf file(only text) parsed with pdfbox.

### Code is as follows

```
public static void PdftoText(InputStream input) 
{
    PDFParser parser ; 
    COSDocument cosDoc;
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
    PDDocument pdDoc;
    String parsedText;
    try
    {
        parser = new PDFParser(input);
        parser.parse();

        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);

        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();


        if(pdDoc != null){

            pdfStripper.setWordSeparator(":");
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);

            System.out.println(parsedText);             
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

And here is the exception i am getting

```
03-26 13:17:57.046: I/dalvikvm(951): Failed resolving Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument; interface 1617 'Ljava/awt/print/Pageable;'
03-26 13:17:57.079: W/dalvikvm(951): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;' failed
03-26 13:17:57.366: D/dalvikvm(951): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 314K, 13% free 3097K/3528K, paused 278ms, total 278ms
03-26 13:17:57.366: E/dalvikvm(951): Could not find class 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument', referenced from method org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.getPDDocument
03-26 13:17:57.377: W/dalvikvm(951): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2233 (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;) in Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdfparser/PDFParser;
03-26 13:17:57.377: D/dalvikvm(951): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
03-26 13:17:57.596: I/dalvikvm(951): Failed resolving Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument; interface 1617 'Ljava/awt/print/Pageable;'
03-26 13:17:57.696: W/dalvikvm(951): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;' failed
03-26 13:17:57.707: D/dalvikvm(951): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x39b3 at 0x06 in Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdfparser/PDFParser;.getPDDocument
```

Comment: Try this Pdfbox for android
https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to use [TomRoush/PdfBox-Android](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android)! I had exactly the same problem and it solved it, so why not trying! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As of now it is not possible to directly use PDFBox in Android due to the awt dependencies.
If you only need to extract text from PDF then you may also try https://github.com/RatheeshRavindran/PDFBoxLight

This is Android porting of PDFBox I recently did, note it is still in Beta version.